# Combing object array by removing duplicates in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a data object

```
data : [
["1", 20],
["1", 24],
["1", 2],
["1", 32],
["1", 23],
["1", 80],
["2", 3],
["2", 32],
["2", 34],
["2", 36],
["2", 36]]
```

Now I want the object to be grouped like this ie "1" grouped in one array and same for the "2"

```
"data" : [
["1", [20, 24, 2, 32, 23, 80]],
["2", [3, 32, 34, 36, 36]]
]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you getting stuck? Otherwise what is the question?

Comment: data.forEach(function(element,array,index){

          aCategories.push(element[0]); 
          aSeries.push(element[1]);

          })

      };
this gives me all the values into 2 different variable, but i feel this is not an efficient way to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OriDrori/8ptkga2c/) - look at the console):

```
var obj = {
    data : [
        ["1", 20],
        ["1", 24],
        ["1", 2],
        ["1", 32],
        ["1", 23],
        ["1", 80],
        ["2", 3],
        ["2", 32],
        ["2", 34],
        ["2", 36],
        ["2", 36]]
};

function group(data) {
    var mapObj = data.reduce(function (map, item) { // create a map of the key: [values]
            var key = item[0];
            var value = item[1];
            map[key] && map[key].push(value) || (map[key] = [value]);
            return map;
        }, {});

    return Object.keys(mapObj).map(function (key) { // map the keys and values back to arrays
        return [key, mapObj[key]];
    });
}

var newObj = {
    data: group(obj.data)
};
```

Comment: if my data is
data : [
 [{
  "d" : "1",
  "v" :"one"
  }, 20],
 [{
  "d" : "1",
  "v" :"one"
  }, 24],
 [{
  "d" : "1",
  "v" :"one"
  }, 2],
 [{
  "d" : "1",
  "v" :"one"
  }, 32],
 [{
  "d" : "1",
  "v" :"one"
  }, 23]
 
};

ie the first element of the array is object then how it would be? it is bit confusing me.

Comment: If d is the key then var key = item[0].d; If the object itself is the key, that's a problem because after .toString() it will be "[object Object]", and the array would be [[object object], [values]].

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what are you trying to achieve, but that's one way you can structure such an array:

```
   var ones = ["1",[]];
   var twos = ["2",[]];
   var data2 = [];

function go() {

    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
       minidata = data[i];


            if(minidata[0] === "1") {
               ones[1].push(minidata[1]);

            } else if ( minidata[0] === "2") {
               twos[1].push(minidata[1]);
            }

    }

   data2.push(ones);
   data2.push(twos);

  console.log(data2);
}
```

Check the console to see the results.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tdby8wec/5/)